# Wireframe material for a loaded .obj - Three.js

Tags: three.js, wireframe

How do you either show or load a wireframe material for a loaded .obj in three.js?

Comment: `object.material.wireframe = true` Doesn't work?

Comment: nope? which version of three.js should that work in?

Comment: Any. Specifically for me, it worked since r68, as I haven’t worked with earlier revisions. Could you show how you load the object and apply wireframe to it? Or a link to download the object?

Answer (score 1):

### You need to set the object.children, Try this.

```
    // MTL SETUP
    const mtlLoader = new MTLLoader(manager);
    mtlLoader.setBaseUrl( '../../../../assets/3D_models/brain/' );
    mtlLoader.setPath(  '../../../../assets/3D_models/brain/'  );

    mtlLoader.load(this.brain_mtl_path, (materials) => {
      console.log(materials);

      // materials.preload();

      // OBJ SETUP
      const objLoader: any = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
      objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
      objLoader.load(this.brain_obj_path, (object) => {

        console.log(object);

        object.children[0].material.wireframe = true;
```